# Select quantity report for all product rows for each category including no matching rows

Tags: postgresql

I have tables like below

1. Product

[image]

2. category

[image]

3. Inventory

[image]

I want to prepare an SQL query that can output like below:

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think your labels for the inventory and category tables are switched up there. This is a basic join. You can write it several ways, but explicit JOIN statements are the syntax you should be using for the most part.

```
SELECT
  prd."skuCode" as "Product",
  ctg.name as "Category",
  COALESCE(inv.qty, 0) as "Quantity"
FROM product prd
FULL JOIN category ctg ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN inventory inv ON inv.product_id=prd.id AND inv.category_id = ctg.id
```

[Here's a short explanation of joins](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-joins/) with some examples. It's important to really study them until they're second nature when you're working with any RDBMS.

Comment: The joins will return the matching rows only. It will not return the rows where every quantity is 0 for each product within each category. @john-morton

Comment: OK, I see now. I've modified my query to better answer your question.